# dynamic n-bit modules in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am wondering if it is possible in verilog to create an n-bit carry lookahead adder. With some help from the comments I've been able to come this far

```
module nbit_lookahead(x, y, cin, cout, s);
  parameter n = 1;
  integer i;
  integer j;
  input wire [n:0] x, y, cin;
  output wire [n:0] cout, s;
  wire [n:0] g, p;
  reg cpp, gp;
  generate
    cpp = 1; // ERROR HERE -- Line 25
     gpp = 1;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i=i+1) begin : outer_loop
      assign p[i] = x[i] | y[i];
        assign g[i] = x[i] & y[i];
        assign s[i] = cin[i]^x[i]^y[i];
        for(j = i - 1; j >= 0; j=j-1) begin : inner_loop
           cpp &= (cin[j] & p[j] & p[i]); // ERROR HERE -- Line 32
           gp &= (g[j] & p[i]) & gp;
        end
        assign cout[n] = cpp | gp | (x[i] & y[i]);
    end
  endgenerate
endmodule
```

The challenge I'm having now is how to assign cpp and gp. I keep getting errors:

> Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at fourbit_lookahead.v(25) near text: "=";  expecting ".", or "(". Check for and fix any syntax errors that appear immediately before or at the specified keyword.

> Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at fourbit_lookahead.v(32) near text: "&";  expecting ".", or "(". Check for and fix any syntax errors that appear immediately before or at the specified keyword.

Comment: I don't know if this will help at all, but [here's an alu32 implementation](https://gist.github.com/patrickroberts/3908606ece975eb4c20b4cd8f8b25dd6) using a `parameter` and a `generate` block. Since your `n` isn't just a value that's transferred over a wire and it's actually determining what hardware to synthesize, it needs to be a `parameter` rather than an `input`. At least that's how I understand it.

Comment: Thanks for the help @PatrickRoberts I have updated my question to reflect a specific error I'm getting. Any ideas?

Comment: Keep in mind the `generate` does not support sequential logic. Instead of declaring two `reg`, maybe declare two sets of wires to accumulate the `(cin[j] & p[j] & p[i])` and `(g[j] & p[i])`?

Comment: forget about generate blocks. There are very special. You have a ton of problems there. You do not really need them here. Try to use always blocks instead.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty rusty, but mixing wires and regs looks wrong to me in the for loop. The first thing I would try here is to make cpp and gpp bit vectors, so that everything is parallel. That way you don't have any reassignments in the inner loop. In generate, your have cpp[0]=1'b1, and gpp[0]=1'b1, then in the inner loop, assign cpp[i+1] and gpp[i+1] to your value. It also looks wrong to be setting cout[n] inside every iteration of the loop. You should be setting cout[i] based on cpp[i] and gpp[i].